# Tampermonkey script with automatic fill of file input?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, tampermonkey

I am working on a tampermonkey script that fills out a form on a website. Everything is working fine, like filling in my name or birthdate. But there is also a file input field for a profile picture I would like to get filled out by my script. Is there any possibility to do this? I would be fine by uploading it from my computer or from another website.

Comment: make form droppable and bind drop event to input element files object

Comment: Gonna try it, thanks!